# What type of pipe should I use in my drain/leach septic field?

Tags: drain, pipe, pvc, septic

I have an older house and its septic somewhat failed. Leach field pipes were not glued and they all disconnected immediately after d-box so that none was going into the field. These are also **very weird** ABS pipes sized as SDR35 pipe (modern ABS is much thicker wall and won't fit but PVC from HomeDepot does fit), it says **DF256 UABS  BNO 3624-130** on the pipe. The perforated pipe in the field also all flattened under the soild weight.

I am going to redo all this nonsense and am wondering what would be a good pipe to use in the septic field itself (after d-box). I was [able to find](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffeZYXtwVpE) some people use [ADS 3000 triple wall HDPE pipe](https://www.adspipe.com/pipe/triple-wall) whereas others seem to suggest SDR35 PVC pipe (green ones). The local Home Depot sells [those white perforated pipes](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ipex-homerite-products-pvc-4-inches-x-10-ft-perforated-sewer-pipe/1000658914) but it seems their compression rating is about 46psi and I heard septic people on YouTube specifically saying not to use those from home depot. I also read that SCH40 pipe is **NOT** recommended underground due to cracks from expansion/contraction. On top of it I find some documents mentioning Corrugated Polyethylene (PE) Tubing complying with ASTM F 405

I am not planning to drive over my septic field nor do I plan to put any concrete, but I don't want to dig it out again in few years so I don't mind throwing some additional money in to make it right. It's Vancouver area Canada in case it matters. Thank you!

Comment: Doing your septic field yourself, is probably not allowed(unless behind the house, out in the boonies, where no one can see).  Septic fields are usually heavily regulated.

Comment: I understand. But a) yes, I am in the bush and b) I am "just" replacing the already installed 40 years ago pipes, so technically it is not a new one. But thanks for a comment

Comment: The "Don't use sch 40 underground" bit sounds like a complete myth to me. It's the same material as 35, just more of it so it's sturdier. As for gluing joints in a septic field, pretty much never - the pipes should not be moving far enough to pull out of the slip joints. Since they did: it points to poor practricces when installing the field. Crushing pipes is almost always from improper backfilling...

Comment: thanks, @Ecnerwal. So would you say SDR35 is the way to go for a leach field pipes?